# Exporting data in zoomed in region of MATLAB plot to workspace

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have 4-5 subplots of timeseries data and scatter plots in a MATLAB figure whose x axes are linked. The data is quite long and I've zoomed into a small portion of the figure.Now I want to export just the data contained in this zoomed in portion to work-space as variables. Is it possible?

For example, the following is the plot for the full dataset.

[image]

The following is the zoomed in portion,

[image]

Now I want to export all the variables or time-section of the variables corresponding to the above zoomed in portion to workspace.

Comment: Sure: get the limits of the x-axis with `get(gca, 'XLim')` and index your arrays accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of Ratbert's comment, let's set up a sample plot to play around with.

```
x = 1:10;
h.myfig = figure();
h.myaxes = axes('Parent', h.myfig);
h.myplot = plot(x);
```

I'm going to assume you have MATLAB R2014b or newer, which is where MATLAB [switched graphics handles to objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/graphics-handles-are-now-objects-not-doubles.html). If you have an older version you can swap all of my dot notations with [`get`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) calls, where appropriate.

Now with this initial plot, if we enter `h.myaxes.XLim` or `get(h.myaxes, 'XLim')`, we return:

```
ans =

     1    10
```

Now if we zoom in arbitrarily and make the same call, we get something different. In my case:

```
ans =

    3.7892    7.0657
```

Now it's up to you how you want to use this information to window your data. A very basic method would be to use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to get the indices of the closest data points to these limits.

For example:

```
newlimits = h.myaxes.XLim;
newminidx = find(x >= floor(newlimits(1)), 1);
newmaxidx = find(x >= ceil(newlimits(2)), 1);

newmin = x(newminidx);
newmax = x(newmaxidx);
```

Returns `[newmin, newmax]` of:

```
ans =

     3     8
```

I used [`floor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/floor.html) and [`ceil`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) here because I know my data is integers, your criteria may be different but the process is the same. Hopefully this is enough to get you started.